# Chef processing after remote file downloaded

Tags: ruby, download, chef-infra

I'm trying to run a library function on a remote file after it has been downloaded as part of a chef recipe. The syntax I'm currently using, which seems to work is

```
remote_file "some_file" do
  source "some_url"
  action :create_if_missing  
end

ruby_block "some_block" do
  block do
    runMyScript("some_file")
  end
end
```

This seems a little verbose because all I really want to do is call a single function on the file after it's done downloading. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Don't Chef recipes run in a blocking way? I.e., you don't have to use the blocks at all, just write out your script and the next line will be triggered only after the previous line is done. Won't that work? P.S.: yay Chef ; )

Comment: I don't think that's quite how it works because of the run and compile phase https://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Evaluate+and+Run+Resources+at+Compile+Time;jsessionid=3B9180E469E38DF2A1DAD3370761EE3F. If it's just out in the open, I think it gets executed during the compile phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an [LWRP](http://docs.opscode.com/lwrp_custom_resource.html) to replace this construct.

Additionally you could consider using notifications so that the ruby block only executes once:

```
ruby_block "some_block" do
  block do
    runMyScript("some_file")
  end
  action :nothing
end

remote_file "some_file" do
  source "some_url"
  action :create_if_missing  
  notifies :run, "ruby_block[some_block]", :delayed
end
```

Comment: Thanks I'm not familiar with LWRP - I'll check them out. I have since modified the block to use notifications.